# grep -f when the pattern file also has some empty lines

Tags: linux, bash

Is there any option of the grep command to suppress the effect of empty lines in the pattern file? I would prefer this option than always checking and filtering the nascent pattern file.

Here is an example (in `pattern_file`, there is an empty line):

```
$ cat pattern_file  
APPLE  

PEAR  
$ cat file  
Nothing  
fruit  
$ grep -f pattern_file file  
Nothing  
fruit
```

Comment: Try grep's option `-F`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ignore empty lines in pattern file:

```
grep -f <(grep . pattern_file) file
```

Comment: Yes it is OK but I would like to know that there is an option or not in grep.

Comment: @LászlóSzilágyi, the "option" in grep which determines which lines will be matched is the regular expression itself. A regular expression that forces at least one character to be recognized is precisely what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -v '^$'
```

This actually grabs all the lines except for newlines. You can pipe the result to your grep like this: `grep -v '^$'| otherGrep`

Comment: Just beat me for 5 seconds with `grep -v` :) Ok, I added the `sed` solution.

Comment: Sorry, @John_West. But this is the easiest way. You grep the text without empty lines and forward it to your own grep.

Comment: You can't put the filtered pattern file after -f option in the other grep command without using a temp file.

Comment: @LászlóSzilágyi what -f? I didn't even suggest that. I recommend you using the -v option, like I posted/mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Is `grep -v '^$'` any different from `grep .` ?

Comment: @ghoti, what is the purpose of your question? I simply used a grep that takes all the lines that are not empty lines and forwards it using the pipe `|`.

Comment: The purpose of my question? To point out that the set of "all lines that are not empty" is also the set of "all lines that contain at least 1 character". Depending on one's needs, it may be preferable to use fewer (just one?) greps in one's command line by eliminating the need to *negate* a regex in an earlier pipe. Of course, your answer doesn't address the problem described in the question in the first place, so I suppose the greater purpose of my comment is to enlighten rather than correct. Of course, cyrus' answer did that too.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I see, and I understand your answer and I agree with it/you. For example, I didn't remember about the -f option, so nice one! If you need only one grep, I agree that your solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

About `-f` option:

> A null pattern can be specified by an empty line in [pattern_file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html).

So, it is a feature, and you should [delete empty lines](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-command-remove-all-blank-lines/), e.g. with `sed`:

```
sed '/^$/d' | grep -f ...
```